# How do I install paystack to my laravel app?

Tags: pos

I am new to using laravel and paystack. I have tried running all the commands, but it's not working out. If one could help me with steps to achieve this, I will love it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site expects you to do some work, so please show us what you've started. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).